# Integer tetrahedron division.

Tags: polyhedra, solid-geometry, packing-problem, tiling

Let an integer tetrahedron be a tetrahedron where all edge lengths are integers.

Can an integer tetrahedron be divided into smaller integer tetrahedra?

Comment: Obviously _some_ can't (such as the 1-1-1-1 one). Whether there are _any_ that can sounds like a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Construction 1**:

$A(-3,0,0), \quad B(3,0,0), \quad C(0,-3,\sqrt{7}), \quad D(0,3,\sqrt{7})$.

$|AB|=6, \; |AC|=5, \; |AD|=5, \; |BC|=5, \; |BD|=5, \; |CD|=6$.

When add point $E(0,0,0) \in AB$, then new tetrahedra $AECD$ and $BECD$ are integer too.

**Construction 2**:

$A\left(0,0,-\frac{577}{2}\right), 
\quad B\left(0,0,\frac{577}{2}\right), 
\quad C\left(\frac{\sqrt{1155}}{2}, 0, 0\right), 
\quad D\left(\frac{24\sqrt{579}}{\sqrt{1155}},\frac{3}{2\sqrt{1155}}, 0\right)$.


$|AB|=577, \; |AC|=289, \; |AD|=289, \; |BC|=289, \; |BD|=289, \; |CD|=24$.

When add points:
$E_{1,2}(0,0,\pm\frac{1}{2})$, 
$E_{3,4}(0,0,\pm8\frac{1}{2})$, 
$E_{5,6}(0,0,\pm15\frac{1}{2})$, 
$E_{7,8}(0,0,\pm23\frac{1}{2})$, 
$E_{9,10}(0,0,\pm39\frac{1}{2})$, 
$E_{11,12}(0,0,\pm56\frac{1}{2})$, 
$E_{13,14}(0,0,\pm95\frac{1}{2})$, 
(which belong to $AB$), 
then each tetrahedron
$AE_jCD$, $BE_jCD$, where $j=1,2,...,14$, is integer tetrahedron too.